# Saving non-English (Hindi, Chinese, etc.) to SQLite

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am working on an iPhone app where I need to save some data in non-English languages, for example, Hindi, Chinese, Arabic, etc. to an SQLite database. Is it possible to do it?

I have tried to search about it on the web, but I could not find anything. So I am not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Frameworks on iOS will "just work". They'll use appropriate string encodings to cover Unicode, which includes all written languages. SQLite will use UTF-8, so that's fine too. If you don't mess with the string by using C-style encodings or messing with the string bytes directly, you should have no problem.

If you *do* mess with the string bytes directly (like modifying characters based on an index, where the index is bad) then you may have problems, because you might accidentally create something that's not valid UTF-8. There's more detail on that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261786/how-to-handle-non-standard-unicode-characters-in-coredata/29905163#29905163). But that's almost never necessary, and even in that case it was never clear how people had managed to corrupt their data.

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [mySQL cStringUsingEncoding: [NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]
```

`defaultCStringEncoding` is for taking only English.

`NSUTF8StringEncoding` is for taking any language.

Change `defaultCStringEncoding` to `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Comment: SQLite always uses UTF-8.