# How to handle non standard unicode characters in CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data, unicode

One stuff I read on the web is this

Rameeee!

So it uses non standard character.

I tried to save that to coredata

```
   NSManagedObjectContext * parentMoc = [self managedObjectContextMainContext]; //Main parent is not nsmainqueueconcurency type. Hence, this is save
    [parentMoc performBlockAndWait:^{
        if (![parentMoc save:&error])
        {
            CLog(@"Error in Saving %@", error);// handle error
        }
    }];
    NSAssert(error==nil, @"Error must be nill");
```

I got this error:

```
(lldb) po error
domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 1671
```

Hmm... what should I do?

Comment: The character “” U+1F46F WOMAN WITH BUNNY EARS is not nonstandard; it was added to the Unicode Standard in version 6.0.

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: @Devfly Can you describe your app a little more? Where are you getting these characters from before assigning them to a managed object?

Comment: I ask because I tried with both your string and Jim Thio's and I can't reproduce the problem. More detail on what your code is doing is needed.

Comment: so how do I save that kind of character to core data?

Comment: In my experience, the same way as any other string and/or character. That's why I asked for more detail about what your code is doing, because there's no obvious reason why saving these characters would be different than saving any other characters.

Comment: as said in the question, I got the error

Comment: if I can just remove these very rare characters it'll be great

Comment: @SharenEayrs This is why I keep asking you for more detail about how your code works, because there must be more to the problem. As long as you refuse to provide any more detail it's going to be impossible to provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 20):

Error code 1671 is not documented. However error codes 1660, 1670, and 1680 deal with string validation errors. So let's see what we can find...

**Valid** strings work the same regardless of whether they have Emoji or whatever. As long as the string contains only valid characters, no special treatment is needed. The string that prompted this question-- *as posted*-- fits this description. This code works, and changes save without errors:

```
NSString *testNSString = @"Rameeee! ";
[newManagedObject setValue:testNSString forKey:@"name"];
```

A full round trip works exactly as expected, even displaying correctly in a `UILabel` in a text view cell.

[image]

As a result it's clear that the original question is leaving out crucial details somewhere, because the correct answer is that you don't do anything special to handle those characters, they just work.

The sample string from @DevFly provides a clue:

```
"\U05d4\U05d4\U05d9\U05ea\U05e8\U05d2\U05e9\U05d5\U05ea \U05db\U05dc \U05db\U05da \U05d2\U05d3\U05d5\U05dc\U05d4 \Ud83d"
```

You actually can't construct a string literal with these contents without some significant difficulty. The compiler complains that the last character, `\Ud83d` is an "invalid universal character", and compilation fails. Taking a look at [the relevant code chart from unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UD800.pdf) confirms this: `\Ud83d` is in the "high surrogate area" and the chart notes that

> Isolated surrogate code points have no interpretation; consequently, no character code charts or names lists are provided for this range.

What all this means is that `\Ud83d` is not a valid Unicode character. It does not represent any character and cannot be converted to encodings like UTF-8.

If you drop the invalid character from the end, then just like above it works normally with no special handling:

```
char *testString = "\u05d4\u05d4\u05d9\u05ea\u05e8\u05d2\u05e9\u05d5\u05ea \u05db\u05dc \u05db\u05da \u05d2\u05d3\u05d5\u05dc\u05d4";
NSString *testNSString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:testString];
[newManagedObject setValue:testNSString forKey:@"name"];
```

That saves without errors, and again makes a complete round trip and displays correctly in a `UILabel`:

[image]

What all this means is:

- This error means that you're somehow constructing a string that contains invalid bytes that don't represent any character.
- This is *not* because the characters are Unicode, because *valid* Unicode is fine. But not every numeric hex value represents a Unicode character, so it's possible to have a corrupt value that can't be used in a string.
- Since neither @JimThio nor @DevFly nor @SharenEayrs seems to want to explain how they created their problematic byte vectors (I can't really call them "strings") it's impossible to say what originally caused the problem. But **that data is corrupt, period**, and it only looks like a Core Data problem because that's where you're using the data.
- A *likely* cause is that at some point these strings were altered in code without considering that not every character uses the same number of bytes. Doing things like changing strings based on character indexes is likely to cause problems. It might be helpful to review Apple's ["Characters and Grapheme Clusters"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html) guide and maybe the NSHipster [article on type encodings](http://nshipster.com/type-encodings/).
- @mmarkov's suggestion of using `NSData` **might** work but probably not, unless you resort to bizarre code where you avoid using those bytes in a string at all (e.g. you don't use `dataUsingEncoding:` to convert to `NSData`). Even if it does, *you would still have corrupt data*, and it would bite you sooner or later.

**Update** related to a string given in a comment:

```
NSString *testNSString = @"                                ☝      ✌  ✊ ✋     ";
[newManagedObject setValue:testNSString forKey:@"name"];
```

Again this saves without errors, and comes back to the UI later exactly as shown above, including after killing the app and re-launching. If this is somehow breaking, it's not Core Data that's corrupting it.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you Tom. Excuse my late reply. I am aware now that the example I have provided is an invalid string - I was doing modifications on it and cut half of the supposed "Face throwing a kiss" emoji. However I've found the issue to be true on a string that is totally valid. Here it is, and you can test for yourself:                                 ☝      ✌  ✊ ✋     

Comment: @Devfly updated answer a bit, this string works the same as any other for me.

Comment: Thank for your explanation. Now i know \Ud83d caused the issue.

Comment: Tom seems to be completely right!
In my case using 'NSString substringToIndex:' turned a valid string to an invalid one, when emojis were used in the string. The reason for this was, that 'NSString length' works a bit different to lstrlen()...
@zaph gave a good explanation to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23789463/2778898

Answer (score 0):

`NSCocoaErrorDomain` errors with codes between 1024 and 2048 are validation errors. One of the validation rules that has been set in the model is not passing.